Declaration of MobileFormatter::parseItemsToRemove() must be compatible with HtmlFormatter
Using Mediawiki 1.39.8, php 8.1 (tested with 8.0 and 7.4 too) I am getting this error and a 500 browser error when I try to use the MobileFrontend extension.

Fatal error: Declaration of MobileFormatter::parseItemsToRemove() must
be compatible with HtmlFormatter\HtmlFormatter::parseItemsToRemove():
array in MobileFrontend/includes/MobileFormatter.php on line 67

In LocalSettings.php I use:
wfLoadExtension( 'MobileFrontend' );
wfLoadSkin( 'MinervaNeue' );
$wgDefaultMobileSkin = 'minerva';

Edit: Looks like it is an issue with HTML formatter versions.
If I use in vendor/wikimedia/html-formatter HTML formatter 3.0.1, MobileFrontend works BUT TextExtracts/Popups DO NOT work (I get "There was an issue displaying this preview").
Conversely with HTML formatter 4.0.3, TextExtracts/Popups work but not MobileFrontend.
Submitted a bug report.

Try composer update in: 1) MediaWiki folder, 2) skins/MinervaNeue, 3) extensions/MobileFrontend.

Please see edit, I regressed to HTML formatter 3.0.1, and now MobileFrontend works BUT TextExtracts/Popup DO NOT work
